# Why are all files overwritten by index.html when deploying VueJS app on Nginx Kubernetes?

Tags: vue.js, kubernetes, nginx

I have deployed my VueJS app using Kubernetes and an Nginx base image. All seems fine when navigating to the homepage, which is just /, and then navigating in the app. Vue Router correctly picks up the routing and suppresses serving new HTML pages when navigating the app.

The problem arises when a user goes to a page which is not the homepage, e.g. /settings/profile, and then refreshes the page. I then see that the subdirectory settings/profile is being served instead of the root. A strange thing is that the js and css folders are being served, with js and css files in them. The content of all those files has been overwritten by the content of my index.html.

The js and css files I am talking about are the app files which are created when the app is built.

I have set up an nginx.conf file which I am putting in the etc/nginx folder when deploying.

These are the contents:

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        location / {
            root   /app;
            index  index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            autoindex on;
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
  }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea where the issue lies?